# ImageResizer Watermark doest'n work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

I use ASP.NET MVC.. I use imageresizer and i need watermark image. If i use a text for watermark there is no problem. But when i use a png image for watermark it doesn't work. Watermark doesn't appear on my images.
How can i solve this problem?

Thank you.
Note: watermark.png is exists

```
imageJob = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file,
                Const.UploadFolder  + "_<guid>.<ext>",
                new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(
                    "watermark=test1;width=1024;quality=100;format=jpg;mode=max"));
imageJob.CreateParentDirectory = true; 
imageJob.Build();

//web.config
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" />
</configSections>
<resizer>
<plugins>
  <add name="Watermark" />
</plugins>
<image name="test1" path="~/watermarks/watermark.png" align="topleft" width="100%" height="100%" relativeTo="canvas" drawAs="Background"></image>
</resizer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is invalid. <image> tags must be contained within the <watermarks> element. Please see [the documentation](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/watermark) for an example.